# Firebase Database updates slowly sometimes not at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, firebase

Good morning everyone, I have a question regarding the behavior of my firebase database.

I am populating an end point on my database `user` with multiple POST requests to  my express server `app.js` from my client like so:

```
element.on("click", function(){
  send request 1 - endpoint1
  send request 2 - endpoint2
  send request 3 - endpoint3
}
```

Then in my `app.js` I have handlers at the routes that use the Request package to make three seperate GET request to the Halo Waypoint API like so:

```
app.post(endpoint1, function(req,res){
  request(HaloAPI + endpoint1, function(error, res, body){
    [store data from the response body into an 
     object to be sent to firebase endpoint 'user']
    // User's stats
    database + "/user".set(dataObject)

  }
}    
app.post(endpoint2, function(req,res){
  request(HaloAPI + endpoint2, function(error, res, body){
    [store data from the response body into an 
     object to be sent to firebase endpoint 'user'.
     This is a url for an image]
    //This is a player's emblem
    database + "/user/emblem".set(dataObject)

  }
}

app.post(endpoint3, function(req,res){
  request(HaloAPI + endpoint3, function(error, res, body){
    [store data from the response body into an 
     object to be sent to firebase endpoint 'user'.
     This is a url for an image]
    //This is a player's Spartan portrait
    database + "/user/spartanImage".set(dataObject)

  }
}
```

I'm expecting the database to be updated all at the same time; however, that is not the case all the time.  Usually when I click the button with the event listener attached endpoint 2 and 3 come in at the same time as the data from endpoint 1, but most of the time I only get data from only endpoint 2 **or** only endpoint 3. Eventually I stop getting the data from endpoint 2 and 3 all together. In fact, with this current setup I can see the endpoints `user/emblem` and `user/spartanImage` populate in the database console but then they are taken away as soon as they are added. This has been troubling me from the beginning of this project and I would really appreciate some insight from someone more experience in Firebase than myself. Below I will link my relevant code, thanks in advance for the help.

`request.js` is where the initial AJAX calls are made client-side:

```
$searchButton.on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // the value of the search field creates the request object
    // it is just a user's Xbox Live Gamertag and is used for the
    // the subsequent requests.
    var $search = $("#searchField").val();
    $.post(homeRoute + "statSearch", {search: $search}, function(data){
        console.log(data)

    });

    firebase.database().ref().on("value", function(snapshot){
    function ez(path){
      return snapshot.child(path).val();
    }

    var dataObject = { 
      gamertag: ez("gamertag"),
      totalKills: ez("totalKills"),
      totalDeaths: ez("totalDeaths"),
      totalGames: ez("totalGames")
    };    

    console.log(dataObject)

  });

    $.post(homeRoute + "emblemSearch", {search: $search}, function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });

    $.post(homeRoute + "spartanSearch", {search: $search}, function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
```

From there we go over to `app.js` my express server to make GET requests to the Halo Waypoint API and send the response formatted with the data I want to firebase:

```
app.post("/statSearch", function(req, res){
    var search = req.body.search;

    var statsOptions = new Options("https://www.haloapi.com/stats/h5/servicerecords/warzone?players="+search);

        request(statsOptions, function (error, response, body) {
          if (error) throw new Error(error);
          var body = JSON.parse(response.body)

          var playerData = {
            gamertag: body.Results[0].Id,
                totalKills: body.Results[0].Result.WarzoneStat.TotalKills,
                totalDeaths: body.Results[0].Result.WarzoneStat.TotalDeaths,
                totalGames: body.Results[0].Result.WarzoneStat.TotalGamesCompleted
          };
    res.send(playerData)
    var userRef = ref.child("user");
    // sending off the data object to Firebase at the "user" endpoint
    userRef.set(playerData);
        });
});

//emblem
app.post("/emblemSearch", function(req, res){
var search = req.body.search;
var imgOptions = new Options('https://www.haloapi.com/profile/h5/profiles/'+search+'/emblem', '512');

        request(imgOptions, function (error, response, body) {
          if (error) throw new Error(error);
          var imgString = response.request.uri.href;

          res.send(imgString);

          var emblemRef = ref.child("user/emblem");
          // sending off the url to Firebase at the endpoint "user/emblem"
          emblemRef.set(imgString);
        });
});

//spartan image 
app.post("/spartanSearch", function(req, res){
var search = req.body.search
var spartanOptions = new Options('https://www.haloapi.com/profile/h5/profiles/'+search+'/spartan', '256');

request(spartanOptions, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  var imgString = response.request.uri.href;

    res.send(imgString);

    var spartanImage = ref.child("user/spartanImage");
    // doing the same as emblem to this endpoint^^^^
    spartanImage.set(imgString);
    });
});
```